# Filesystem Hook for .doc open C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, filesystems

I'm writing an application that needs to be notified of every doc file that is opened, I've tried using the `FileSystemWatcher` but it seems that these days `NotifyFilter`.`LastAccess` is disabled due to a large overhead.

There is `LastWrite` which I suppose I could use but it would mean I'd need to try and figure out the original file name from the temporary file that word creates when it opens a document.

I also need to keep watch on 4 directories so ideally I don't want to be polling them.

I'm aware I could write a `WordAddin` which is one option but that means another deployment to manage, another codebase and another product to support along with the problem that many users always see addins as a source of slowdowns.

Is there a straightforward way to tell windows Vista upward that I want to know about doc or docx that is opened?

One thing I was wondering about is if I could alter the default program associated with .doc to mine, which is running as a service and then passing the details through it to mine to be opened? This seems like a bit of a hack so I was wondering if there was an easy way to hook into these sorts of file open?

**UPDATE**

From talking it through with various people here the most reliable way(and most resource effective) would seem to be to replace the existing file association for .doc.  & .docx to my own program and then use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to launch word and then hook into the DocumentOpen event.

That way I get the file name thats being opened along with any future documents that are open in word.

Comment: Note that if you re-associate .doc / docx to your own app, you won't be notified if the user opens Word and then uses the Word UI to select the file and open it.

Comment: ProcMon is able to do what you need. So then the question is, how does ProcMon do it? I don't know, but the answer may be out there somewhere.

Comment: Hrm good catch I didn't think about file open from within word, you're sure it doesn't still do a lookup? I don't suppose it would really. Lemmy have a look at procmon

Comment: Hmm actually surely if you opened word through the interop assembly you could hook into the fileopen dialogue no?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Word interop, but it sounds promising.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, the temporary file that is created in the same folder has the file name format of ~$ + filename, for example:

> ~$very_important_file.doc

It contains the name of the user that opened the file. Note that the file has the hidden attribute set.

This makes it quite easy to figure out which document is actually open and by whom.

Comment: I thought that'd be the case but it renames the first two characters to ~$ so it's not 100% reliable for determining whats been opened

Comment: If the file name (without extension) is shorter than 7 characters, it prepends the ~$, if the file is longer it starts replacing the first or the first two characters. If you have multiple files with file names longer than 8 characters that differ in the first two chars only, that could be a problem (Word only creates one temp file for both documents in those cases)

Comment: Hrm thats a possibility I suppose, i'm surprised there isn't an easy way to hook into file open though

Answer (score 1):

Such tasks are usually accomplished using filesystem filter drivers. Procmon works this way. You can create your own filter driver or use the precreated one (eg. our CallbackFilter).

Comment: Thanks for this for the alpha I'm using a fs watcher on the c:\users\whatever but yes I think the filter driver would be the way to go for production