# Replace File type association C# Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word, interop

As a follow-up to [Filesystem Hook for .doc open C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26796897) i'm trying to figure out the following for a WPF application.

I want to replace the file association for .doc & .docx with my own program which will run at windows start-up.

My program will then simply open a word with the documented requested but with the added benefit of being able to hook into events like `Office.Interop.Word.DocumentOpen` - this way i'll be able to get everything thats ever opened by word without a filesystemwatcher or something similar.

What is the best practice way of doing this and how do I overwrite Words' association with the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use these two commands

[ftype](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490912.aspx) and [assoc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490865.aspx)

[Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1469764/3970411)

Comment: Hrm ok that looks pretty good, let me do some checking on how i'd get return status for it

Comment: also "ftype /?" in cmd may come in hande

Comment: Yeah that actually looks very interesting since it means i don't have to mess around with figuring out the version of office, which has knock on benefits for my software, i'm just checking if I can grab the output from command and check it executed ok

Comment: Hrm if I do ftype .doc =<space> it deletes the association but when I click on .doc it still opens it with word

Comment: Ahh hold on I was being a dumb ass two ticks its ftype .doc Word.Document.8=<space>

Comment: os version? office version?

Comment: Windows 8.1 office 2013 - looks like ftype/assoc should be fine down till vista? Looks like you're heading nicely toward a winner here!

Comment: I think all versions of windows >= xp support them

Comment: Providing I can reliably execute these in C# i'll tick this, the added benefit is I can determine which version of office is in use which really helps with other aspects, its possible I actually love you

Comment: Right i'm gonna mark this as correct since I can execute these commands from a batch file if needed and then get the result from the batch file output. Thanks!

Comment: Solition here with an update for windows 8/10
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681878/associate-file-extension-with-application/40405884#40405884